# Rounding in R and IEEE 754

Tags: r, rounding, ieee-754

**Context**

R's `help()` function indicates that `round()` adheres to a standard that is identical to IEEE 754: round halves to even.

Wikipedia describes this standard with the following example: *23.5 becomes 24 and 24.5 becomes 24*.

`help()` also states, ...*this is dependent on OS services and on representation error*.

**Experiment**

*System details*

- R version: 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
- Arch / OS: x86_64, darwin18.7.0 (MacOS)

On my machine, I see that

```
round(0.55, digits = 1)  # [1] 0.6
round(1.55, digits = 1)  # [1] 1.6
round(2.55, digits = 1)  # [1] 2.5
round(3.55, digits = 1)  # [1] 3.5
```

**Question**

Should I attribute the discrepancy between the first two and second two statements as *errant OS services and or representation error*?

Comment: See the edit. Without `digits = 1` it rounds to integer. Also, what are the OS and version of R?

Comment: I suspect `2.55` is stored in IEEE double, hence would not be exactly 2.55, but instead apparently `2.5499999999...((plus garbage))`.  Hence it is correctly rounding "down".